# why confusion matrix is not compatible with the accuracy?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am doing Bert fine tuning on my multi class text classification.
The accuracy and Loss plots are as below.

`1 -` my learning rate for Adam is learning_rate= 2e-5, which learning rate is better to start with? that my accuracy start to goes up from low number rather that 79%. For example it starts from 50% to 70%  and it goes up.

`2-` why my confusion matrix shows that I have a very few accuracy? Do you thank it is normal compared to loss and Accuracy plots?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely you are shuffling the data so predictions and labels don't match; leading to random confusion matrix.

Comment: yes I think this is the case

Comment: do you think my model is learning?

Comment: No, leading to overfitting as validation loss tends go higher, training loss behaves the exactly opposite. In other words, failing to generalize the training set.

Comment: so do you think this very bad behaviour in confusion matrix is becuse the model is not learning?

Comment: No as I already mentioned it is most likely because of shuffling the data. That confusion matrix seems like random guessing.

Comment: yes that's true , I removed shuffling and it got solved